# How do I push to git from Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

The following code is an "Execute Shell" build step in Jenkins. The job pulls from a repo which contains a file `ranger-policies/policies.json`. What I'd like to do is update that file (with a curl command, in this case) and then commit the change to source control and update the remote repo. The job successfully pulls from the remote repo in the "Source Code Management" section of the job configuration page over SSH using SSH keys. However, when the job gets to the "git push origin master" line in the "Execute Shell" step, I get a `Permission denied (publickey)` error, as if those same SSH keys which allowed me to successfully pull the repo are not available in the "Execute Shell" step when I want to push.

```
curl -X GET --header "text/json" -H "Content-Type: text/json" -u user:pass "http://my-url.com/exportJson" > ranger-policies/policies.json

git add ranger-policies/policies.json
git commit -m "udpate policies.json with latest ranger policies `echo "$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"`"
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ended up figuring out how to make it work. The solution involves using the SSH Agent plugin. Here's a step-by-step that describes how I did it, hopefully it helps someone else:

1. First, create a new pipeline job.
2. Then, as hinted at in [this](https://gist.github.com/blaisep/eb8aa720b06eff4f095e4b64326961b5#file-jenkins-pipeline-git-cred-md) post from Jenkins' documentation, go to the home screen for your new pipeline job, and click on "Pipeline Syntax." Choose "git: Git" as the "Sample Step, and enter the git repo you want to push to in the "Repository URL" field. Then choose the corresponding valid SSH keys for that repo from the "Credentials dropdown." Everything should look like this: 
   [image]
   Grab the value of "credentialsId", highlighted with red in the above screenshot. You'll need it later.
3. Install the "Workspace Cleanup Plugin" (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin, optional) and the "SSH Agent Plugin" (https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/, not optional, required for this process to work).
4. Now go back to your new pipeline job and hit "Configure," which will take you to the screen where you define the job. Drop the following code into the "Pipeline" section ("Definition" should be set to "Pipeline script"): https://gist.github.com/ScottNeaves/5cdce294296437043b24f0f3f0a8f1d8
5. Drop your "credentialsId" into the appropriate places in the above Jenkinsfile, and fix up the repo names to target the repo you want, and you should be good to go.

Relevant documentation:

1. https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#push-git-repo
2. https://gist.github.com/blaisep/eb8aa720b06eff4f095e4b64326961b5#file-jenkins-pipeline-git-cred-md
3. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28335?focusedCommentId=269000&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-269000

Answer (score 1):

As per this [gist](https://gist.github.com/developius/c81f021eb5c5916013dc), you need to set the remote origin url as per:

`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/your-repository.git`

Comment: I just tried adding that line per your suggestion, but I get the same error as if nothing had changed. I think the problem is somehow related to the SSH keys being unavailable in the context in which the "Execute Shell" step runs. I could copy the valid SSH key into the Execute Shell step directly, but that would present a security hazard. I'd like to be able to use the valid SSH key that Jenkins already has stored in its database - the same one that allows me to successfully fetch the repository up in the "Source Code Management" panel of the configuration page.