# How to copy a file from one repo to another repo [Jenkins]

Tags: git, jenkins, gradle, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have created a Jenkins job that uses a groovy script (gradle) to download a file.

```
    stages {
    stage('Import and Unzip') {
        steps {
            cleanWs()
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                branches: [[name: "$GIT_BRANCH" ]],
                extensions: [[$class: 'PruneStaleBranch']],
                userRemoteConfigs: [[
                    url: 'git@github.com/repo1.git',
                ]]
            ])

            script{
                bat './gradlew --build-file scripts/Jenkins/build.gradle'
            }
            
            
            dir('scripts/Jenkins') {
                bat '../../../gradlew downloadfile'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So now when I run this job I have a file in the Jenkins workspace ...

I want to add and commit it on another github repo :   **git@github.com/repo2.git**

Any ideas how to do it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47410648/1744774) help? And, BTW, usually one `add`s and `commit`s to a local repo and `push`es to another/remote repo: „[_git-push – Updates remote refs using local refs,_](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)“.

Comment: The trick isn’t to move from source to destination repository. It’s to clone both repositories, remove the file into the dir that repo2 is cloned in, then add/commit/push. Please see my answer and accept it if it was helpful

Comment: Copying build artifacts and checking them into source code is bad practice; you should using an artifact managee like Nexus, Artifactory or GitHub Packages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

You should be able do the following

1. Create a new directory in your workspace
2. Checkout the repository you wish to push to ( I'm calling it repo2.git )
3. Copy the file from the workspace to the new directory you created ( the one where repo2 is cloned )
4. Run the appropriate git commands in bat

> Without knowing the name of the file, repository, or repository branch I can't give you exact code, but it should look something like the following

## Sample Code

```
stages {
    stage('clone repos') {
        steps {
        
            cleanWs()
            
            // clones repo1 in ${WORKSPACE}/repo1
            dir('repo1') {
                checkout([
                    $class: 'GitSCM',
                    branches: [[name: "$GIT_BRANCH" ]],
                    extensions: [[$class: 'PruneStaleBranch']],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[
                        url: 'git@github.com/repo1.git',
                    ]]
                ])
            }
            
            // clones repo2 in ${WORKSPACE}/repo2
            dir('repo2') {
                checkout([
                    $class: 'GitSCM',
                    branches: [[name: "$OTHER_GIT_BRANCH" ]],
                    extensions: [[$class: 'PruneStaleBranch']],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[
                        url: 'git@github.com/repo2.git',
                    ]]
                ])
            }
        }
    }
    
    stage('Import and Unzip') {
        steps {
            dir('repo1') {
            
                bat './gradlew --build-file scripts/Jenkins/build.gradle'

                dir('scripts/Jenkins') {
                    bat '../../../gradlew downloadfile'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    stage('commit and push') {
        steps {
           dir('repo2') {
                /**
                 * Copies the downloaded file from repo1 into the 
                 * directory where we cloned repo2 then executing the 
                 * appropriate git commands
                 **/
                bat '''
                    cp ../repo1/scripts/Jenkins/<filename> .
                    git add <filename>
                    git commit -m "commit msg"
                    git push
                '''
           }
        }
    }
}
```

I refactored your code slightly so that it checkouts the source and destination repositories in separate directories in its own stage.  I think this is a cleaner way to organize the file.

> **Note** you obviously need to replace  with the file you wish to add to the other repository.  You also need to change the repository url in the second checkout block to the actual URL.  You will also need to add $OTHER_GIT_BRANCH as the parameter for the branch you want to push to.  You may need to change the relative paths ( I tried my best without actually building a pipeline )

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Also the code refactoring looks very clean !